# Want to get urls from search results and also from next pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am having trouble to **scrape** the data from website. I am able to **scrape** the text but when i try to extract url then getting error.

this is the url: https://www.horizont.net/suche/OK=1&i_q=der&i_sortfl=pubdate&i_sortd=desc&currPage=1

So far i am using this:

```
r=requests.get('https://www.horizont.net/suche/OK=1&i_q=der&i_sortfl=pubdate&i_sortd=desc&currPage=1')
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
all = soup.find_all('a',  {'class': 'ArticleTeaserSearchResultItem_link'}, href = True)

for item in all:
    print(item.find_all('h2')[0].text)
```

output:

```
Schweizer Illustrierte und L'illustré rücken näher zusammen 
"En Garde" und andere Geschichten über Mut und Beharrlichkeit 
Hüttenzauber - der TV-Spot zu Weihnachten 
Neuwagen in Deutschland müssen künftig DAB+ empfangen können 
Schiess Werbig mit neuen Storys 
Thjnk-Manager Sebastian Schlosser kommt als Chief Marketing Officer 
Die Einreichungsphase läuft bis zum 30. November 
Ipsos / Sinus / YouGov / Appinio / Axis / GfK 
Pro Sieben Sat 1 plant Audio-Streaming-Plattform 
Adidas und DFB blasen in Streifenoptik zum Angriff auf den EM-Titel
```

Problem 1:
I am still not able to **scrape** the urls from the search

Problem 2:
The search result consist of about 15000 pages and i want to **scrape** all the urls.

Comment: your url is not correct.it should be `https://www.horizont.net/suche/?OK=1&i_q=der&i_sortfl=pubdate&i_sortd=desc&currPage=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided link isn't correct.I have changed the link.
However since you have mentioned you need upto 15000 pages I have made loop for this.
To get all the links you need to get the href attribute from link.

```
all_links=[]
for i in range(1,15001):
    url='https://www.horizont.net/suche/?OK=1&i_q=der&i_sortfl=pubdate&i_sortd=desc&currPage={}'.format(i)
    print("url: " +url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    c = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
    all = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'ArticleTeaserSearchResultItem_link'}, href=True)
    for item in all:
        print("https://www.horizont.net" + item['href'])
        all_links.append("https://www.horizont.net" + item['href'])

print(all_links)
```

Now if you do `print(all_links)` in the end you will get all links in a list of 15000 pages.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what i wanted... :)